# Angular 4 Observable fork Join Array

Tags: angular, observable

i have a quick question regarding Angular 4 and the Observable.
In my program i have a Component, which creates a list of "things" that should be send to an api.
Secondly, i have a service, which gets an element ("thing" --> one!), sends it to the api and returns a Observable.
Here´s the code:
Component:

```
saveTimers() {
    // gehe alle selektierten Timer durch und lege Sie an
    let timerSuccess = [];
    let timerFailed = [];
    let timers = [];
    for (let epgEntry of this.searchResult) {
        if (epgEntry.checked) {
            let timer = new Timer;
            // magic
            this.timerService.saveTimer(timer).
                subscribe(
                data => {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data) {
                        timerSuccess.push(timer);
                    } else {
                        timerFailed.push(timer);
                    }
                },
                error => { this.variables.setFailure(error); }
                );
        }
        }
//both empty, because api didn´t return yet
        console.log(timerSuccess);
        console.log(timerFailed);
        if (timerSuccess.length > 0) {
            this.variables.setSuccess('Timer erfolgreich angelegt');
        }
        if (timerFailed.length > 0) {
            this.variables.setFailure('Timer konnte(n) nicht angelegt werden');
        }
    }
```

Service:

```
saveTimer(timer: Timer): Observable<boolean> {
// magic --> returns an observable
}
```

Now the question: how can i use Observable.forkJoin() (in the component) to do ALL api calls at one time (btw wait for all api calls)?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
Observable.forkJoin(Observable.of(YOUR_ARRAY), saveTimer(timer: Timer))
    .switchMap(joined => Observable.forkjoin(http.post(joined[0]), http.post(joined[1])))
    .subscribe();
```

In the first forkjoin you combine your value that you want to send. In the second you combine the results of the two api calls.

Comment: ok, thanks!
But where i have to put this...? In the component instead of the call to the service?
but then 'saveTimer(timer: Timer) won´t work...